# Multiple parameters send as json in body RetroFit without creating a model to hold it

Tags: retrofit

I want to use RetroFit for Android but I don´t like the idea of creating a model for every single request.

Can I create a Service that receive like 2 strings and convert it into a json that should go in the body of the post request?

Comment: This can be helpful for you http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a HashMap and put it as parameter of your request method. For example, something like this:

```
@Body HashMap user
```